# critical mass to support your family -- meaning?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

[Toronto is North America's 4th largest city](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFAWmH12Ivo#t=3m47s) (YouTube video) [at the 3 minute 47 second mark or just click the link and it will get you to the right timing automatically]:

> Toronto has it all in abundance. Whatever you prefer, Toronto delivers. With **a critical mass** to support your interests, your lifestyle, your family, Toronto is dynamic.

I've looked this term up in many dictionaries and to be completely honest still can't make proper sense of what the narrator is trying to say.

Comment: A metaphor (not the best) meaning "enough things going on".   It's from nuclear physics originally--enough fissile stuff to get a chain-reaction going.

Comment: A nuclear reactor becomes "dynamic", that is, producing electric power, once a critical mass is reached. Probably the authors meant to say that their city has high enough concentrations of facilities, services, institutions, businesses etc. to cater to a variety of interests. A small town may have, say, one small library, which would be unsuited to a researcher, but Toronto may have a dozen of specialized big libraries, "a critical mass" in terms of literature available to a researcher - enough to get a serious reseach going.

Comment: @CookieMonster I think this definition would work for you: **[critical mass](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/critical-mass)**: the smallest number of people or things needed to make something happen.

Comment: All of these are answers, not comments. Post them as answers so that you can be credited for them.

Comment: I concur with @TBridges42. Far too many folks post answers in comments and make it incredibly difficult to find the questions that are actually answerless.

Comment: @Omni in fact, the SE solution for comment-answers is to post answers and steal the comments' information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is marketing language, and so it uses words and phrases that sound  impressive and cool without necessarily having a precise meaning (e.g., "has it all", "delivers").

But the idea they're trying to get across with "critical mass" is that Toronto is a big enough city to support a wide variety of interests and lifestyles. It's not a small town with limited options, but a large, diverse city that probably has just about anything you might be looking for.